# Help understanding FPGA dimensions

Tags: pcb, fpga, datasheet

I need some help understanding the dimensions specified in the datasheet of an FPGA.

I am trying to figure out the pad/ball dimensions. From looking at the schematic, it looks like theta_b is the diameter, but then what are the theta_d and theta_e values? Additionally what is the C, A, and B value? I couldn't seem to find any reference to those.

I used the autocad libraries and it appears to be the .5 mm, but would like to have a better understanding/explanation. Is theta_d the radius and theta_e maybe the height?

[image: FPGA Dimensions]

Comment: They may be explained elsewhere in the datasheet ... which could usefully be linked in the question.

Comment: What you call "theta_X" is read as "phi X", and means "diameter X".

Answer (score 4):

⌀b is the diameter of the solder ball: 0.6mm ±0.1mm

[image]
This specifies the positional tolerances.
⌀ddd is the positional tolerance in respect to C, A and B.
⌀eee is the positional tolerance in respect to C.

[image]
This is such a reference marker. I suppose you'll find something similar for A and B.

Unless you're a PCB manufacturer, I wouldn't lose sleep over these tolerances. It's more important that you're designing the solder pads according to the manufacturer recommendations.

---

Furthing infos regarding geometric dimentioning and tolerancing: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_dimensioning_and_tolerancing)

Picture: [fictiv](https://www.fictiv.com/articles/gdt-101-an-introduction-to-geometric-dimensioning-and-tolerancing)

[image]

---

PS: ⌀ is a [diameter symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter) and not related to [θ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta).